# Static Qt linking version , Qt 5.2, Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml

Tags: c++, qt, windows-8, windows-7-x64, static-linking

I need to have **Stand-Alone .exe file** of my project.
I knew that I have to get static Qt version linking.

I can’t run QML project by Static Qt linking version , **Qt 5.2 rc1** on Windows 7 or Windows 8

An error occurred:

**Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml**

It’s very simple project of built in qml “Hello World” message.

I downloaded qt-package-opensource from :

http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0-rc1/single/

Also, I found that is ageneral bug for many peaple,

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28357

But, any fix didn’t solve my problem.

Any help, please,

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have QT += qml quick in the .pro file?

Comment: yes, i use this : CONFIG += static qt import_plugins
,QT += core gui qml quick widgets network
,QTPLUGIN += qtquick2plugin
,DEFINES += STATIC_BUILD

Comment: Why do you use the release candidate? By now the current version is 5.2.1.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, Sorry I didn't understand, I'm new in Qt, can you more explain please ?

Comment: @amt: "RC1" means "release candidate 1", i.e. it's a package for testing created shortly before the 5.2.0 release. It's meant for testing before the actual release, not for productive use. For that, I'd recommend 5.2.1, which is the latest bugfix release.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld ,Thank you, I follow that now.

Comment: Qt 5.2.1, make errors in cmd, this errors doesn't be in 5.2 rc

Answer (score 1):

You first have to build a statically configured Qt itself. Then you don't need to do anything special in your project at all, apart from the usual care needed to link in the static plugins.

Merely building using statically configured Qt will link it statically into your project.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I built static version but I had this error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml
So I couldn't to run a release for any QML project, what can I do ?

Comment: @amt Did you build *and* install those two modules?

Comment: I'm new in Qt, How can I install them ? isn't build of whole Qt make every thing ?

Comment: @amt 1. You have to run configure from the root folder of the source tree (not from qtbase). 2. Run [n]make. 3. Run [n]make install.

Comment: I follow your steps, an error said: 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: also, when I tried mingw32-make, I had error: resipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed, I work from root folder, what can i do please

Comment: If nmake is not recognized I suppose you built with jom on Windows. Then use "jom install" but it installs in [drive letter]:/usr/local/qt-5.9.0. To solve this issue I did this jom install and moved all folders into qtbase folder... Dirty fix... I suppose there's a cleaner solution. Anyone ? Maybe using -developer-build ?