# How to get Stand-Alone .exe file of QML project, Qt 5.2

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I need to have **Stand-Alone** .exe file of my project. I knew that I have to get static Qt version linking.

I can’t run QML project by Static Qt linking version , Qt 5.2 rc1 on Windows 7 or Windows 8

An error occurred:

**Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml**

It’s very simple project of built in qml “Hello World” message.

I downloaded qt-package-opensource from :

http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0-rc1/single/

Any help please,
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static Qt linking version , Qt 5.2, Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808954/static-qt-linking-version-qt-5-2-unknown-modules-in-qt-quick-qml)

Comment: I dont know, the other is about errors in static Qt build, here I try to back to original need which is export stand-alone exe file, I ask if it is possible without static build of qt.

Comment: No, because "static build" *means* "build a stand-alone .exe".